# How to debug apache camel route in quarkus application using eclipse

Tags: maven, apache-camel, quarkus

I want to know, is there anyway to debug my camel route using quarkus framework in eclipse

Comment: Have you tried any standard way to debug the issue, please expand that and add what you had tried

Answer (score 1):

Start your Quarkus application in debug mode with JVM with;

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev -Ddebug
```

then attach a debugger to localhost:5005.

Answer (score 0):

if u are use quarkus cli start your application with dev mode

```
quarkus dev
```

if u are not use quarkus cli u can use mvn for run quarkus app dev mode

```
mvn compile quarkus:dev
```

after run application add remote debugger from eclipse with default quarkus opens 5005 port for debugging